# Opening corrupted Excel file with Python via COM interface

Tags: python, excel, com-interface

I'm trying to open an excel file using COM interface in Python.
Normally it's easy but this time I have problem with opening the file that is corrupted.
Error I get looks like this (partially in Polish):

```
com_error: (-2147352567, 'Wyst\xb9pi\xb3 wyj\xb9tek.', (0, u'Microsoft Excel', u'Open method of Workbooks class failed', u'xlmain11.chm', 0, -2146827284), None)
```

I coped with such problem previously in VBA by using additional parameter `corruptload:=xlRepairFile` in Open method.
Do you have any idea how to do it in Python?

Below code doesn't work.

```
excel.Workbooks.Open(latest_file, CorruptLoad = "xlRepairFile")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
excel.Workbooks.Open(latest_file, CorruptLoad=1)
```

There's an example [here](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-win32/2008-April/007330.html) of someone getting it working. Their full example is:

```
xlApp = Dispatch("Excel.Application")
wb1=xlApp.Workbooks.Open(inputfile,ReadOnly=1,CorruptLoad=1)
xlApp.SendKeys("{Enter}",Wait=1)
xlApp.DisplayAlerts = 0
xlApp.Quit()
del xlApp
```

They also note:

> The DisplayAlerts is needed to prevent Excel from asking if it should
>   save a file that was opened as ReadOnly in the first place.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't help in my case. As a workaround I think about running VBA code from inside of Python but it doesn't seem to be the best practice...